# Extending the Array.prototype

Tags: typescript

I can extend Array.prototype and use it in javascript like that:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'flatten', {
  value: function flatten() {
      return this.reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), []);
  }
});

// that allows me to do:
[1, 2, [3, 4]].flatten(); // [1,2,3,4]
[1, 2, [3, 4]].map(e => 5).flatten(); // [5, 5, 5]
```

However under typescript I get an Error: **Property 'flatten' does not exist on type 'Array[]'.**

I can avoid that doing something like the following, but that is not nice to get a fluent interface...it's harder to read.

```
 (<any>[1, 2, [3, 4]]).flatten()
 ([1, 2, [3, 4]].map(e => 5) as any).flatten()
```

Can I do something in typescript to avoid a casting to any? Like let to know typescript dynamically than the code of type Array has another method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extend the `Array<T>` interface to add the `flatten` method:

```
declare global {
    interface Array<T> {
        flatten(): T[]
    }
}
```

Note that you only need to wrap it inside `declare global` only when you are inside a module. See [merging interfaces.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces)